# libreoffice headless wait for completion

Tags: powershell, libreoffice

I'm converting word files to pdf files using `soffice` (on windows with powershell).

Calling the following code works pretty well:

```
$soffice = "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" 
& $soffice --convert-to pdf "c:\temp\somefile.docx" --headless --outdir c:\temp
```

However, the command exits immediately, before the pdf is actually created.

Is there anyway to wait for completion, before returning to the prompt?

I fear that batching multiple conversion spawn dozen of process and saturates the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I simply have to spawn the process using `Start-Process` specifying to wait for completion:

```
    Start-Process -FilePath $soffice `
                  -ArgumentList "--convert-to pdf ""c:\temp\somefile.docx"" --headless --outdir c:\temp" `
                  -Wait
```